# Unable to ping ip of class c with class b network..?

Tags: networking

Unable to ping ip of class c with class b network..??
i put my ip to  172.16.1.50 and at the other side 192.168.1.50

Comment: Yes we can ping the class C network with an Class B IP ,the only thing we need is to create an alias eth0:0 with the address of class C. Try this http://www.mylot.com/w/discussions/2101117.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Host 1 (172.16.1.50) --- (192.168.1.50) Host 2

If the above is what you have, this is quite simply an invalid configuration.

Host 1 (172.16.1.50) --- (172.16.0.0/24) Router (192.168.1.0/24) --- (192.168.1.50) Host 2

Will work, if you correctly setup the routes on the two Hosts so that they know that they need to send the packets to the Router to get to the other side.

Comment: i satisfied with your suggestion sir, but is it possible to connect 2 connect them with the same IP configuration without using router as well by providing virtual ip to eth0 of C-class :)

Comment: What you suggest is this: Host 1 (172.16.1.50, 192.168.1.1) - Host 2 (192.168.1.2). This will work, but this does not mean 172.16.1.50 can communicate with 192.168.1.2. It simply means 192.168.1.1 can communicate with 192.168.1.2. Multi-homing makes sense if you have Host 3 (172.16.1.51). Then Host 1 can communicate with host 2 via 192.168.1.0/24 and Host 1 can communicate with host 3 via (172.16.0.0/16).